# Xcode: Missing private key

Tags: ios

I'm trying to add iOS Distribution and iOS Development certificates to another mac, but after downloading and installing I get the error missing private key. How to fix it?

Comment: From which mac you've created the certSigningRequest file? The same mac you need to export .p12 certificate and install on other mac's.

Comment: @Imad I reinstalled the system on a mac

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you are not copying only the public key (.cer).

You should export the private key (.p12) through the *Keychain Access.app* from the old mac:

- In the certificates tab, look for your *iPhone Distribution: John Doe* or *iPhone Developer: John Doe*
- Click on export.
- You will need to enter a password to generate a .p12 file containing the private key of your certificate.

This file is what you should copy to the new mac, where you will need to import it (using the password). You should be able to use the provisioning profiles when the certificate is installed on the Keychain Access.app

Comment: What if I reinstalled the system on a mac?

Comment: If you don't have access to the certificates installed on the old mac, and you never exported those private keys, you won't be able to retrieve the private key you need, as the private keys are generated attached to the computer where they were generated (using the .csr file)

Answer (score 3):

You need to export the private keys from the system from which they were created (the system whose CSR was used to created the certificates). Without private keys you the certificates do not work.

Comment: What if I reinstalled the system on a mac?

Comment: @Artem If you have lost the private keys and there are no copies available of it, then you will have to create new certificates, also try to keep a copy of certificates and their private keys. For eg: add them to the git repository over which you commit your code

Comment: I need to create a new iOS Distribution and iOS Development? And the old iOS Distribution and iOS Development will work with existing applications in the app store? And in-app purchases will be work fine?

Comment: As long as the app id is the same, you should not have any problems. The certificates expires anyways, so it is perfectly fine to generate new certificates

Comment: @Koesh And if I need to update the app with Provisioning Profiles was created with the old certificates. What should I do?

Comment: @Artem Provisioning profiles can be re-generated with the new certificates and used in tour current app without any problems. Push notifications certificates are linked to app ids, not to provisioning profiles or distribution / developer certificates, so it should work fine too

Comment: @Artem If you used any payment gateways and used the old certificate to create merchant certificates then, it will stop working if you revoke the old certificates. Rest of the app should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I fix it deleting the certified from http://developer.apple.com and create a new one since manage certifies on xCode